# Optimizing nginx for video streaming

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, video-streaming, html5-video, jwplayer

I'm new to nginx, so please bear with me...

I have a Tomcat/JSP application whose primary purpose is to serve video via JWPlayer.  The application is currently hosted on my laptop, but it will be migrating to an Amazon AWS EC2 instance.

On that same EC2 Instance, I have an nginx server set up to deliver said video content.  Right now I have about 15 videos that I am serving as a single playlist.  These videos range in size, with the smallest one being ~40 MB.  The problem is that buffering is taking too long, and I'm trying to figure out how to optimize this.

I have tried to increase my buffer size in the nginx.conf file as follows:

```
location /videofiles {
            # activate flv/mp4 parsing for pseudostreaming
            flv;
            mp4;
            mp4_buffer_size     24M;
            mp4_max_buffer_size 48M;
    }
```

I have also tried increasing the chunk_size (though I can't find any doc on this property):

```
    chunk_size 16384;
```

Here is some other potentially useful config info from nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  10;  

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  client_max_body_size 100000M;
}

keepalive_timeout  65;
```

For perspective, I have FIOS and my upload/download is 15Mbps, but the content is coming over at about 15Kbps (according to the Charles app).  I would have expected it to stream much faster...

Are there other properties I can set to help optimize this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you prepare those files for progressive download (`moov atom` placed at the beginning of the MP4 files, metadata tracks for FLV seeking)?

Comment: I haven't.  Can you please explain more about this?

Comment: There's a brief explanation on the mp4 module page, including a link for preparing FLV: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html. The idea is that the client needs the metadata to start the playback/seek and if you didn't prepare the files then Nginx will have to read them and do it for you each time adding some overhead.

Comment: I think that that's the doc I was using when I initially set those buffers (at top of original post).  Perhaps the nginx server isn't using this location...  Is there a way to confirm that?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/456153/nginx-mp4-module-buffer-limits-are-being-ignored) those buffer sizes are for processing and not client-side buffers. Try encoding one of the `mp4` files using FFmpeg and [-movflags faststart](http://walterebert.com/blog/start-playing-mp4-videos-before-download-has-finished/) and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I've confirmed using AtomicParsley that the moov atom is at the beginning of each mp4 file, so that doesn't appear to be the issue...

Comment: Do you have an example of where the player is running?